# iPhone - Merge keys in a NSArray (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, merge, key, nsarray

I'm having troubles with arrays and keys... I have an array from my database:

```
NSArray *elementArray = [[[menuArray valueForKey:@"meals"] valueForKey:@"recipe"] valueForKey:@"elements"]
```

The problem here is that I would like all my elements of all my meals of all my menus in an array such that:
`[elementArray objectAtIndex:0] = my first element
etc...`
In the example above, the elements are separated by the keys.
How can I get that?

Hope it's clear enough...

Thanks

Comment: Clear as mud. ;-) Can you provide a little insight into how the data is structured?

Comment: OK... I don't know if it will clarify the problem but let's try!
I have a user which has a one to many relationship with menu which has a one to many relationship with meal which has a many to one relationship with recipe which has a one to many relationship with element.
What I would like to get is all the element of three of my menus in an array...

Hope it is clearer ;o)

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it is not clear to me exactly how your data is structured, but I think it's analogous to having an `NSDictionary` (called `aDictionary`) of `NSArray` and wanting to combine all the `NSArray` into one.  If this is the case, then:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
for (id dictionaryKey in aDictionary) {
    [resultArray addObjectsFromArray:[aDictionary objectForKey:dictionaryKey]];
}
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:resultArray];
```

(This code has not been tested.)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for... but thanks! Look at my comment (of my own question)

Comment: Are you using key-value coding and/or CoreData?

Comment: Yes, I'm using core data. The problem is when I get an array of objects (such as my three menus) [user.menu allObjects], I can reach its properties (such as meal, recipe and element) with keys [[user.menu allObjects] valueForKey:@"meal"]. 
But like I said above, I would like all my elements in an array